# Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing on EC2

Tags: apache, magento, amazon-ec2, fonts

I have a site on Magento, and need fonts from other server, but the fonts are blocked by the browser, Firefox says: *Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing*, so, I already have this in .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
     Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

and this on the httpd.conf

```
<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

and this on the index.php from Magento:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

but I still having the trouble...

The server is on EC2 with load balancer and security group from AWS, and I already restart the apache after modifications, and clear cache from Magento.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: To be clear, those Apache settings are on the Magento server, or the font server?

Comment: Hi Mark, those are on the Magento server

Comment: Then those settings are pointless. You would have to setup CORS on the server hosting the fonts.

Comment: I put the configuration on the server with the fonts but still doesn't work...

Comment: please explain the configuration of the font server. Is it apache as well? Do you have cloudfront in front of it?

Comment: header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); Fixed my problem. After hours and hours a single line of PHP! Thanks!